# $http.post is not sending the request?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do an `$http.post` and get the response, I tried in several ways but I can't get it working. The data I am sending (userData) is an json object.

I am accepting data in Excel content addin app from user and converting into json to post the data to Restful web service in c#.
Here is the piece of code:

```
function postData(url, dataToLoad){
    var deferred = $q.defer();     

    deferred.resolve($http.post(url, dataToLoad).success(function(data) { deferred.resolve(data); }));
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

We have tested using through POSTMAN tool and it work fine but when trying to use it through angularjs, we are not getting any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, hope this will solve your problem

```
function postData(url, dataToLoad){
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve($http.post(url, dataToLoad)
                .then(function (data){ deferred.resolve(data); },
                function (data){ deferred.resolve(data); }));
return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isha.

As i can see from your code, you're resolving your deferred object immideately.
In your case to make it work right you need to make some changes.

```
function postData(url, dataToLoad){
  var deferred = $q.defer();     
  $http.post(url, dataToLoad)
    .success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

But in this case you don't need to use deferred at all. You can just make an http post request

```
function postData(url, dataToLoad){
  return $http.post(url, dataToLoad);
}
```

Comment: Sorry , but no success...Dont know why it is not hitting the service

Comment: This is really strange. I think you should check if postData function is being invoked. Then check network tab in your browser's developer tools to determine, whether the request is sent and does the browser get the response from the server.

Comment: Checked, postData function is getting invoked. But unable to check whether the request from excel addin content app is reaching the service or not.

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comment, you can check developer tools of your browser to see, whether the HTTP request is being made after invoking postData function.

Comment: I am calling from Excel addin content app using angular js and we are not getting anything in the browser neither GET nor POST request but my Get request is working from excel addin.

Comment: I you are not getting anything in the browser (meaning that request wasn't complede), then you're calling the wrong URL. But if you are calling your backend service and not getting desired result, then it's obsiuos, that this is a wrong request (e.g. not all required headers are set, or not enough parameters).

Comment: at my end GET request is working properly , it means there is no issue in the url and we have tested the same using POSTMAN tool , same we have tested for POST Request , it getting called when used through POSTMAN tool but not from excel addin content app. So here is the piece of code

Comment: var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: dataToLoad, // Javascript object
            json: true, // Use,If you are sending JSON data
            url: baseUrl,
            headers: {
                'content-type' : 'application/json',
                 'Content-Length': dataToLoad.length
            } is there anything else to add in the headers

Comment: I don't know why aren't you getting any response. I suggest you debugging your application with chrome developer tools to see what is actually happening when you are calling your method and check network tab to  examine network activity during your function call.

Comment: Hi Isha,Excel addin requests could not track browser network tool. So you can use fiddler to track your web-request and fiddler show the request result, In case request failed so your request become red otherwise it show the returned result .

Comment: Thanks Aniket, yes fiddler helped me a lot...in finding the mistake